# Is this StaticRandom class thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

The program I am writing is a game server which will have multiple sessions in separate thread. To avoid unnecessary lock waiting time, `[ThreadStatic]` was added.

The program will include some async functions and
`ThreadSafeStaticRNG`(this class) will be used in async.

```
public class ThreadSafeStaticRNG 
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static Random r = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// get random number from [min,max)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int GetNext(int min, int max)
    {
        int n;
        lock (r)
        {
            n = r.Next(min, max);
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

I need verification for;

1. As I understand, worker thread created with `async`/`Task` will not have separate `ThreadStatic` instance. So lock is necessary.
2. If above is true, only restriction in `lock` is that `await` cannot be used in `lock`. So it is safe to use `lock` in `async function`.
3. (edit) `lock (r)` for `r` instance, is it okay? Official document and other codes I looked created other `object` for only `lock`.

Comment: @UweKeim Yes I did research and did not have clear answer for two questions. That is why I said `I need verification`, as the information was not from official documents.

Comment: My fault, didn't read your question good enough, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code shown is (excessively) thread-safe and not correct (can generate same/synchronized random values).

[ThreadStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) guarantees that each thread (either created by hand of taken from thread pool) has its own instance of the variable. As result you don't need to `lock` as long as you don't expose that variable outside (as shown in your code).

Each thread at each moment of time can only run one function - whether it is part of `async` method or function passed to thread. Thread will not switch between functions in the middle of the execution so there is no way two calls to `GetNext` will be made on the same thread in parallel at the same time.

Note that creating multiple `Random` objects quickly can lead to [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) - check this particular [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473510/477420) for proper initialization of such per-thread instances `Random` (using incremental seed).

Comment: Sorry I didn't read entire answer. So, in this case  the `async` will have independent `RNG`and lock is completely unnecessary am I correct?

Comment: @YukiNyaa I strongly suspect you need to read https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+task+vs+thread... Yes, lock is not necessary. "in this case the async will have independent RNG" has no answer - linked search should be able to help you with that.

Comment: Note also that OP's initialization of the [ThreadStatic] doesn't do what might be expected.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx, where a Note states: Do not specify initial values for fields marked with ThreadStaticAttribute, because such initialization occurs only once, when the class constructor executes, and therefore affects only one thread. If you do not specify an initial value, you can rely on the field being initialized to its default value if it is a value type, or to null if it is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Task/Async *might* not have a seperate Thread assigned to it, and a Task *might* be executed on multiple threads.
2. Yes its safe to use Lock, and with the non-thread-safe Random
   function, neccessary to do so. There is no need to mix Lock and
   ThreadStatic. Its more obvious in your intent to use Lock() in my
   opinion, and leave off ThreadStatic.
3. Its normal to create a new Object and lock on it, rather than a lock on the operational object,but in your case its not incorrect to do so.

Perhaps a better pattern would be to invert the problem and get the caller to pass in an instance of a new Random() object into the code which depends on it. This would guarantee a unique instance of Random for each task, and also be more declarative and testable (passing in IRandom and using a test substitute in unit-test land would be the best overall solution.) - for unit testing you need predictible results, not random results, so the ability to substitute a known-number generator for a random-number generator via IOC would be important.

Comment: Thanks. I should consider using different approach for RNG itself.